# Dredd-like tool for swagger?

Tags: swagger, apiblueprint, dredd

Is there a tool like Dredd (for API blueprint) that can be used with Swagger schema?

I would like to use such a tool to automate testing  - have swagger schema files document my API, and then use such a tool to automate tests.
The tool should have the following ability:

- Define the endpoint (including host and port) to run the test against
- Have descriptors or meta data for each test that define which schema  file to use and what example payload to use, and what is the expected response

Comment: Since v1.1.0 released the other day, Dredd is now the Dredd-like tool for Swagger.

Answer (score 4):

There's a Swagger2Blueprint converter (https://github.com/apiaryio/swagger2blueprint), you could use it to setup your workflow with Dredd and Swagger files.

Comment: Yes, we are considering to move out from blueprints.
And  I happen to find dredd a bit flaky, especially around hooks that need to populate DB entries.

Comment: What exactly you mean by flaky around hooks? So we can improve it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using SoapUI for doing so.  You can import a swagger definition and create a number of tests automatically.  See [here](https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui) for the source, and you can always download the application pre-built.